# How to use model loopback in other process nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, process, model, loopback

Normally when I run file server/server.js, that will boot the loopback app and I can use the models loopback.

Now I have other program nodejs (not loopback), that need to access to database. How can I **include the models of loopback** to manipulate data ( insert, update, delete, select) in my file nodejs ?

Thank you

Comment: more details with example please

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize and use loopback models and other functionalities without starting loopback app as a server. Sample Code

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
app = module.exports = loopback();

//create a datasource
app.dataSource("mongo", {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "connector": "mongodb"
});

//create a model from JSON defination
var Model = loopback.createModel({ ... });

//attach model to a datasource and app
app.model(Model, { dataSource: "mongo" });
```

Once models are attached to app, you can start using them as usual through `app.model.ModelName`. I have used this to create an npm script for a project.

Comment: Thank you abskmj. But I want to use all models in common and datasource existing without defining new datasource or models. You know how to do that ?

Comment: You can read the json files by using `fs` module and pass the file contents to above mentioned functions. This is how I have written a migration script as a npm script for the project. It loads all the models and source datasource from the application and start migrating to another datasource created from script configuration.